# Update issue on play store

Tags: android, installation, updates, google-play

I developed a small application that I gave to a friend by installing via my PC.

After several tests I decided to put the apk on the store play. In the same time, I update from version 1 to version 2.

I gave the link to my buddy and when he went to the play store he saw two options : "Open" and "Uninstall" but not "Update".

If he clicks on "Open" it launches version 1, not 2 (necessarily, since there was no update)

Do you know if I posted my application wrong or if it is because the first installation was done via the PC and not the store?

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Earlier when you installed the app in your buddy's phone was the apk signed?

Comment: Ask him to uninstall it from your app's page on play store and again install it from play store

Comment: Did you update the android:versionCode and android:versionName fields in your Manifest File?

Comment: yes the two apk was signed. Yes I update android:versionCode from 1 to 2 and I check on app store I update version 2. The problem is my app have a database and if he uninstall the app all the data will be remove...

Answer (score 1):

the publish takes more time sometimes, please wait 2-3 hours for new apk.
And maybe the problem is the `cache` of *google play* app on phone. please exit and enter again to detect new apk.
(your buddy has the app which is the version is 1 right?)

Comment: yes he has version 1. I'm not sure it's the cache because version 1 never was on play store...

Comment: so try the other option please